# Setting up a new table saw blade

Tags: table-saw

I just got a new table saw blade (Freud 50 tooth combination, thin kerf) to use on my portable / contractor saw (blade was almost half the price of the saw!). Is there anything in particular I should do to the saw or blade before I begin cutting? I figure I need to check the angle and make sure it's perpendicular to the table, but anything else?

Comment: With mine I just but it in there. One thing I guess you can do is run a piece of wood through. I did that to see if there is wobble since it can be hard to notice. And you will know because it will both not cut as good and be wider. other than that use the wrenches and just do your best, it should work out fine.

Answer (score 4):

No, if your previous blade is square then your new one will be too.  It's extremely unlikely for a blade to be bent, especially for a Freud, and even if it is, it'll be obvious as soon as it spins up the first time.

Of course, if your first blade wasn't square then your new blade won't be either, and a new blade is as good a time as any to square your saw :)